# Using WinLess with Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

In the past I've used Bootstrap with its Less files and the WinLess program to compile into a CSS file (this is on my Windows 7 PC). I don't do anything fancy with Less, just change some of the values in Bootstrap's variables.less (mainly colours) and include my own styles in a custom.less file.

I haven't used Bootstrap for 2 years but now have to start a new project and I thought I'd use the latest version of Bootstrap, V3.3.7. I downloaded the source files and went to set everything up when I noticed on the Bootstrap Getting Started page that Autoprefixer is required when using Less/Sass. Specifically it says:

> Bootstrap uses Autoprefixer to deal with CSS vendor prefixes. If
>   you're compiling Bootstrap from its Less/Sass source and not using our
>   Gruntfile, you'll need to integrate Autoprefixer into your build
>   process yourself. If you're using precompiled Bootstrap or using our
>   Gruntfile, you don't need to worry about this because Autoprefixer is
>   already integrated into our Gruntfile.

I'm sure when I did this with older versions of Bootstrap that there wasn't this Autoprefixer requirement.

I'm not using Grunt (I don't know anything about Grunt or if it would even work on my Windows 7 PC). I can't find any mention of WinLess working with Autoprefixer, so I assume it doesn't. If I use WinLess to compile the Less code into CSS will it work but I won't get the vendor prefixes added? Will this cause me problems? Is anyone using WinLess with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and if so how did you get around this requirement?

If I can't get Less working then what's a good way to customise the Bootstrap colours and include my own CSS? Maybe I could just use the pre-built bootstrap.min.css and put all my own CSS into a custom.css file? This will work for adding my own styles but what if I want to change the colour of Bootstraps buttons or other items?

Comment: "If I can't get Less working then what's a good way to customise the Bootstrap colours and include my own CSS?" - the answer is in the question: "Use Grunt" (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt).

Comment: And to answer your main question: "Will this cause me problems?" - yes, w/o Autoprefixer your compiled CSS won't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a small one-off project it's probably not worth the hassle of trying to get WinLess working or struggling to set up Grunt, etc. Best to just use [Bootstrap's Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) feature to pick the components to include and the colours to use; this will create a customized bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js file, and also a config.json file that can be used to re-customize without having to start from scratch if needed.

Then put all my own custom CSS into a custom.css file.